# How to show numerically that a subgroup of SU(2) and CNOT gate can give us a finite group?

Tags: clifford-group

Imagine that I have a two-qubit system, and one of the qubits performs single-qubit rotations from a subgroup of SU(2), specifically 2O. In this subgroup, the single-qubit rotations are represented by `H`, `S`,`X`, `Y`, `Z`, and `I`, where `I` denotes no rotation. Additionally, I have a CNOT gate for this system. I am wondering how to show **numerically** that this subgroup and the CNOT gate together form a finite group.

P.S. I understand that this may seem like a trivial question, but I am also trying to grasp the methodology for solving these types of problems, particularly in studying groups and determining whether they are infinite or finite. If someone can provide a comprehensive answer to this question, it will help me understand the approach and process for handling more complex groups as well. I kindly request that any response refrain from phrases such as "with H and T gate, they perform a universal gate set, so if you include them this will perform infinite group" or "it is obvious this will not give us a universal gate set without the T gate and H, so it is finite.

Comment: look into https://www.gap-system.org/ ...as long your groups are "algebraic" (no floating point definitions) it's a pretty powerful software.

Comment: Thank you! Will look at that. Can you give some tips about how to solve that kind of problem?

Comment: you define the set of matrices that generate the group; then you ask GAP to calculate the size of the group. It will give back the size of the group or infinity...

Comment: Excellen! Thank you! And for the interaction of CNOT, then I should include the CNOT gate matrices in the set

Comment: well, actually, I found what to do!! Thank you for referencing the GAP :)

Comment: $SU(2)$ contains only the $1$-qubit gates. In particular, CNOT is not in $SU(2)$.

Comment: @quest if you solve the problem, kindly post the solution here. This is a good problem.